# Compiling a file leaves files in my home directory when doing vagrant provision

Tags: c++, makefile, vagrant, vagrantfile

I am using Vagrant to setup a linux box. I need to add a file I compiled to the system and I do so using the following commands -

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/thewtex/tmux-mem-cpu-load.git /tmp/tmuxcpu
sudo cmake /tmp/tmuxcpu
sudo make clean /tmp/tmuxcpu
sudo make install clean /tmp/tmuxcpu
```

However, this leaves tons of files including a makefile, config files, and other garbage inside the /home/vagrant/ folder. How do I make and install from tmp without littering the home directory with garbage?

The above commands work, but it leaves tons of files in the /home/vagrant folder that I don't want there. Is it possible to cmake, make, and make install without leaving 'trash'?

Comment: Create a "build" directory for cmake/etc. to operate in and use that instead of the default home directory? Also you shouldn't, in general, want or need to run `cmake` or `make` (for the compilation steps) as root.

Comment: So do I need to get vagrant to cd its user somehow into /tmp so I can build from there? I have tried but it seems that after every command, the 'vagrant user" automatically returns to home.

Comment: That means each command is executed in a separate shell, so you'd need to do something like `sudo sh -c 'cd /tmp/tmpxcpu && cmake'` etc. At present the `/tmp/tmuxcpu` argument is probably just being ignored.

Comment: @reinierpost The argument isn't being ignored. It is the source to build. cmake uses the current directory as the "build" directory and takes as argument the source to build from. (This is `srcdir != builddir` in common autotools parlance.)

Comment: But the `make` invocations probably don't do anything useful with it.

Comment: OK, so my advice changes to: create a build directory and `cd` there in the indicated way.

Comment: Thank you both. My issue is now resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue with the help of Etan Reisner and reinierpost.

```
## CPU LOAD
sudo git clone https://github.com/thewtex/tmux-mem-cpu-load.git /tmp/tmuxcpu
sudo sh -c "cd /tmp/tmuxcpu && sudo cmake . && sudo make && sudo make install";
```

My install script now uses the above commands and this has resolved my issue. By keeping the files in /tmp, they are removed the moment I reboot the box. I am using this technique for several other items during the vagrant setup now and it works perfectly. This has solved numerous issues for me.